# CE is independant to choice of CAB why?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: Picture from geogebra]
If points A , B , C are fixed and D is intersection point of two lines ( Angle bisector of A and Perpendicular bisector of BC )
let E is point on line AC such that line ED is perpendicular to line AC
Then length of segment CE is determined by lengths of two segment AC and AB
eg) If AB=12 AC=5 , then CE=7/2